# Proper microservice domain boundaries

Tags: architecture, cloud, domain-driven-design, microservices

Now I'm working on an interesting (at least from my point of view) business case that I have to properly design in a cloud environment.

Let's imagine we have a product service handling all product catalog data e.g. products hierarchy, product descriptions, and product relations. This service has a REST API and provides all necessary APIs to work with products including filtering, sorting, and search.

Now we add one more service: product price service. This service handles all pricing-related logic and calculations including discounts, customers-specific prices. This service also has a REST API that provides a price for the requested product or products.

At this point, the picture seems to be quite simple: we have 2 services with clear responsibilities. From the client standpoint, everything looks quite straightforward:

1. request products
2. request product prices

Now we have a business requirement to add a new filter "Below 20$". Basically, that means we need to have a totally opposite workflow: we need to call the product price service first. In addition, we have a bunch of filters served in the product service that can be easily combined with the new pricing filter.

The business requirement makes me think of the domain boundaries for these services and the only idea is that the boundaries are wrong (even if it was okay at the beginning). Please share your experience/opinion on how to properly define service architecture in such a scenario.

Best regards,
Artur.

Comment: Products have properties, like color, size etc. I assume first service supplies these properties and allows search by those properties. The question is: what is the difference between price and color? they are both properties of the product , right?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I would agree. However, the product properties are static and will not change over time e.g. a plastic toy will be always made from plastic. Product price changes every day depending on various factors like sale campaigns, customer offerings, etc. In addition, price service contains certain heavy calculations like taxes. Basically, these are the reason why we have 2 services.

Comment: What about product service asking price service what conversion to apply for currently logged in customer? price service returns something like "(current_price*0.95)" (kind of resulting discount for the product which is relevant to the customer and current global discounts) . Then product service blindly uses this part in SQL without knowing business reasons. So you could display the price and use filters without any extra intra-service calls and ugly solutions about throwing products out of record-set after they got into service from DB. This is a bit ugly but could keep boundaries logical.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have a single discount rate for our customers. As a customer, you can have a 20% discount on tools and a 10% discount on accessories for these tools - every price is very individual.

Comment: That is what I meant - price service and user service know together what discount to apply for some specific category and current user. They can pass discount details back to the product service. Workflow would be: customer->query product service(filter:"price>234")->product-service-> priceSvc.getDiscount(user, productCategory); priceSvc returns discount to product svc (this is all in context to current customer) ; product svc uses discount information(context specific) to query DB and display data to the customer. product service does not know any business logic but able to query db quickly.

Comment: Unfortunately, the price doesn't depend on the product type. Every product price is very individual and based on multiple factors. Following your logic, we have to pass all product discounts to the product service which is quite a huge value in our environment where we have millions of products.

Answer (score 3):

One possible *(I think, quite main stream)* approach: an [API Gateway](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) implements the [API Composition pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/api-composition.html). In your scenario that would mean API Gateway doing the following steps:

1. Ask Product Prices micro-service for the filtered and paged *(e.g. the first 20)* list of products "Below 20$".
2. Ask Products micro-service for the details of those 20 products.
3. Return with that detailed list of products to the caller Web frontend.

Might this solve your problem?

Comment: One more challenge: what if I want to order these products by rating coming from the product service?

Comment: Not bad :)  E.g. supposing that performance doesn't suffer from too many products: 1) Ask Product Prices micro-service for the filtered list of products "Below 20$". 2) Ask Products micro-service for the details of the first 20 products of those - ordered by rating. 3) same as above :)  I admit, it might happen that performance optimization would be needed to this approach.

Comment: But what if there are thousands of products cheaper than 20$? I have to get a huge set of IDs from the pricing service and pass them to the product service for ranking.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty straightforward trade-off, either you want the product service to know about the customer prices, or you make the filter ignore discounts, and just do it on list price.  This is how most stores filter, they do not take into account personalized pricing.

If you must use personalized pricing, then you need to make a classic time/space tradeoff.  You can pre-resolve all the products to prices, using much more space but much less time, or you can calculate prices on the fly based on discounts, and take much more time.

You can minimize that time by pushing the calculation much closer to the data-store, at the cost of architectural purity.  It is very common to break architectural purity to achieve performance goals, it is just a decision you need to make explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Finding right domain boundaries is mostly about finding minimal required transaction boundaries to design aggregates. And transactions deal with the write side (think CQRS). For the read side you can mix and match any way it is useful. That may be implemented as a separate component: product search service. And it may use ElasticSearch, for example.

If you have a background working in a large mature organisation with many departments and document flows then you can look at the org structure as an example of good domain boundaries and take them for an inspiration. And if an external entity gets any output from such organisation, preparing the output may be the responsibility of some dedicated department.

Talking specifically about your question, it seems like customer level or individual conditions should be managed by some CRM. Which is separate from price service. And, given a product and a base price, CRM should decide what discount or price column to apply.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing a very important point about DDD. Simplifying DDD definition, it describes how to **change** your data (application state) when a **user sends** a command. It doesn't give any guidelines on what to do when a user wants to ask something. This is of course very high-level view.

To answer the question that the user asked, you are perfectly fine to use **any means** necessary to deliver an accurate answer in a reasonable time.

So you can violate any boundaries, read any private state or access the database directly to compute the answer, as long as you don't modify a state of the system.

Some architecture patterns as CQRS, for example, are solely based on this assumption.

Boundaries in DDD (again from the high-level viewpoint) are guidelines on, how to design **write** part of the software.